# CAS Authentication - CSRF token not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas, jasig

I use Apereo CAS (formerly Jasig CAS) ([github here](https://github.com/apereo/cas)). Next, I create a very simple application in Vaadin, which connects to CAS during authentication. Everything works seamlessly until I turned on **CSRF** from **Spring Security**.

If CSRF is turned on, then the redirection to CAS login page works OK. But after the successful authentication (login, passoword), CAS wants to redirect back to my application. Then I see this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1498657046424,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.",
  "path": "/contextPath/"
}
```

I use Spring Boot `@EnableWebSecurity`, so please take a look at the configuration from there:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter())
        .addFilterBefore(singleSignOutFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(casAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();


    http.csrf().disable(); //works when disable
}
```

**My question:**
How to configure Spring Security to make CSRF work properly with CAS authentication?

I'm using Spring Boot `1.5.4.RELEASE` (maven parent) and Vaadin `8.0.5` (BOM).